# Apache Spark GraphX using Cloudera Quickstart 5.7

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm trying to use Spark GraphX using Cloudera Quickstart 5.7 from this website:
http://kukuruku.co/hub/algorithms/social-network-analysis-spark-graphx

The steps that I did:
1) Open Terminal
2) Run `spark-shell`
3) Run `import org.apache.spark.graphx._`

And when I submit this code I obtain the following error:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.graphx_
<console>:25: error: object graphx_ is not a member of package org.apache.spark
         import org.apache.spark.graphx_
```

Anyone have an idea about what I miss to return this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a period after graphx on the import. Instead, use

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
```

For more information, you can reference http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#getting-started